# Delete in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to delete a document of a collection in MongoDB matching a specific condition. I have already used the following commands but they don't seem to work.

```
ClassName.delete_all(conditions: { _id: BSON::ObjectId("whatevertheidis")})

ClassName.any_in(:_id => ["id1", "id2"]).destroy_all

ClassName.where(status: '1').delete_all
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `ClassName.delete_all(status: '1')` will work....... Try

Comment: Can you check if the status field is a string or a integer or just a boolean flag.

Comment: ClassName.where(status: '1').delete_all and ClassName.delete_all(status: '1') both works well if it finds the status field with value '1'